# Linked List implementation infinite loop

Tags: java, linked-list

Here is my code for linked list in java.The code goes into an infinite loop and i am not able to figure out the problem.What could have possibly gone wrong.

```
import java.io.*;
class LinkedList
{
public int data;
public LinkedList next;
LinkedList add(int a,LinkedList ob)
{   
    LinkedList p=ob;
    if(ob==null)
    {
        this.data=a;
        ob=this;
        return ob;
    }   
    else
    {
        while(p.next!=null)
        {   
            if(p.next==null)
            break;
            else
            p=p.next;
        }
        this.data=a;
        this.next=null;
        p.next=this;
    }
    return null;    
}
void display(LinkedList ob) 
{
    LinkedList p=ob;
    while(p!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(p.data); 
        p=p.next;
    }   
}
public static void main(String []args)throws IOException
{
    LinkedList head=null;
    LinkedList o=new LinkedList();
    head=o.add(5,head);
    o.add(6,head);
    o.add(7,head);
    o.display(head);        
}
}
```

The head goes in correctly but further elements are creating a problem.

Comment: Did you try to simulate in your head what the code is doing? Did you try to run it step-by-step using a debugger? What have you done to try to find the bug?

Comment: Use the debugger of your IDE.

Comment: Was just doing it in notepad

Comment: LinkedList should have a node class and then build LinkedList on top of that.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html for eclipse debugging.

Comment: use sysouts if you are using plain old text editors.

Comment: May I assume that your code is going to an infinite loop in the display method?

Comment: @Thihara no its going to an infinite loop on adding the 2nd element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have a LinkedList toAdd too(well this should be a Node, but the way you're doing it it's a LinkedList)

```
LinkedList p=ob;
LinkedList toAdd=new LinkedList();
```

and at the end of the add method where you are setting the parts of it, replace this with toAdd

```
toAdd.data=a;
toAdd.next=null;
p.next=toAdd;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..but how is it different from using "this"

Comment: this is your reference to the linkedlist. So when you try to add 6, it now sets the LinkedList's data to 6, it's next to null, and then the p.next to this, when p was the LinkedList, so it's an infinite loop

Comment: o.add(6,head); When add is invoked in this statement, in add(), this.data=a; Here 'this' is pointing to o. And the code is overwriting o's data with a. So, inturn you are losing 5 also from the List. The code which I have pasted below in my answer will solve the problem. We need not use this pointer to manipulate the list in add() method

Answer (score 2):

After

```
o.add(6,head);
```

In add(),

```
p.next=this; // this is causing infinite loop. A node is pointing to itself.<br>
```

Please refer to the below method of add()'ing to the LinkedList:

```
LinkedList add(int a,LinkedList ob)
{   
    //for creating head
    if(ob==null)
    {
        this.data=a;
        ob=this;
        return ob;
    }   
    else
    {
        // iterate till the last node
        while(ob.next!=null)
        {               
            ob = ob.next;
        }
        LinkedList p = new LinkedList();
        p.data = a;
        p.next = null;
        ob.next = p;        
    }
    return null;    
}
```